# Format cells to show fractions always with 30 on denominator on LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I use LibreOffice Calc to calculate proportional values in fraction format with denominator 30.

30 represents a commercial day in our country, that means the number of days in a month for calculations regardless of its real number of days (i.e., for calculations, January, February and May have 30 days).

So, on LibreOffice we can use the cell format called "fraction" (or format code `# ?/?`), but it always returns the reduced fraction. For example, 0,733 is shown as 3/4.

Also we can use that same format configuring 2-digit for denominator (or format code `# ??/??`), but it returns the minimal fraction for 2-digit on denominator. For example, 0,733 is shown as 11/15.

I am searching for is a format that always returns 30 as denominator, although the fraction returned is not the reduced form nor the minimal form for 2-digit denominator. For the same example, 0,733 would be shown as 22/30.

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That simple:

1. Edit cell format;
2. Choose custom;
3. Use `# ?/30`.